# Метод Хи-квадрат в линейно конгруэнтном генераторе

Tags: c

Университетская лаб.р. на подбор параметров для ЛКГ и проверка его характеристик. Из пунктов есть "проверить полученный генератора методом хи-квадрат". Никак не могу сопоставить метод с лабораторной, то есть не понимаю каким боком он стоял к генератору. Есть идеи? (Язык си, но это не так важно).

Comment: Как я понимаю, вам нужно доказать равномерность распределения генерируемых значений - через [критерий Пирсона](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%9F%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0).